# Debugging code compiled using the Mono.CSharp.Evaluator

Tags: c#, debugging, mono, code-generation

I'm using the Mono.CSharp Evaluator to provide basic scripting functionality for my Windows application.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to debug and step through the scripts created in the application by inserting the Debugger.Break function into the script code.

It's possible to do this with the CSharpCodeProvider as described here: [How to debug/break in codedom compiled code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875723/how-to-debug-break-in-codedom-compiled-code) but I can't seem to find anything on how to do this with the Evaluator.

I've tried setting the GenerateDebugInfo flag and the OutputFile in the CompilerSettings, but haven't had much luck in getting it working.